# Mongoose doesn't seem to support the $max field update operator, any advice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make use of the [the $max update operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/max/#up._S_max) in my Node.js project using Mongoose, but I think that a) I'm either doing something horribly wrong or b) Mongoose doesn't support this functionality.
(Using this as an example):

```
var updateGameScores = function(game, newScore, callback) {
  models.Scores.update({
    gameName: game
  }, {
    $set: {
      $max: {
        highestScore: newScore
      }
    }
  }, {
    upsert: true
  }, function(err) {
    callback(err);
  });
};
```

Gives me the following error:

```
MongoError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$max' in '$max' is not valid for storage.
```

I couldn't find anything about this (or similar functionality) in the Mongoose docs, which suggests that Mongoose doesn't support this.
If that is indeed the case, are there any alternative ways I can achieve this** while minimizing the number of database operations?

**: "update the value of the field to a specified value if the specified value is greater than the current value of the field"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you think $max would do for you in this update?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo In accordance with (my interpretation of) [MongoDB's docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/max/#up._S_max), I was hoping it would only update the highestScore field if newScore is greater than the old field value (and if that field doesn't exist, simply set it to newScore).

Comment: @Soulleswaffle As you can see in the very examples you shared, when you use $max you don't need to use $set, it looks like the the $set is implied by the $max. Maybe that's what's causing the problem.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo You were right, wasn't working because the $max was nested in the $set. Want to add that as an answer so I can give you kudos? :)

Comment: @Soulleswaffle Awesome. I have added a answer to the question as you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider writing your update expression as

```
{ $max: { highestScore: newScore } }
```

Since the $max operator already implies a `$set`.